# Writing stdout to stdin after checking for errors in Vimscript

Tags: vim

I'm trying to read output from `coco` and then pipe it into `uglifyjs`. It sounds simple enough, just to do `coco --print | uglifyjs`, but I want to be able to read `coco`'s output first in the case of an error. For some reason, whenever I save the output and attempt to pipe it into `uglifyjs` through `echo`, I get:

```
E484: Can't open file C:\Users\wuffie\AppData\Local\Temp\VIo####.tmp
```

I hear that error has something to do with the output. Is it echo's fault? I honestly have no clue. If not, here's the code I'm currently using:

```
fu! BuildCoco()
    redraw!
    echo '...'
    silent :w
    let b:out = system(
        \'coco --compile --print "'
        \.expand('%:p')
        \.'"'
    \)
    let b:out_s = split(b:out,'\n')
    redraw!
    if b:out[0:8]!='Failed at'
        echo system(
            \'echo ^\n'
            \.shellescape(join(b:out_s,'\n\n'),1)
            \.' | uglifyjs -b beautify=false --output="'
            \.expand('%:p:r').'.js"'
        \)
    else
        echo join(b:out_s,'\n')
    end
    unl b:out b:out_s
endf
```

Comment: Why do everything in one huge exec statement?  This would be way more readable if you would separate the commands to their own lines.

Comment: You should put that in a function. Then call the function. It will be easier to debug that way

Comment: I honestly never thought of that. I'll do that and update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After screwing around for hours on end trying to uncover the answer, I found out that you're able to pipe variables into commands by supplying `system()` with a second argument. Here's my solution:

```
fu! BuildCoco()
    redr!
    ec '...'
    sil :w
    redr!
    let b:out = system(
        \'coco --compile --print "'
        \.expand('%:p')
        \.'"'
    \)
    if b:out[0:8]!='Failed at'
        ec system(
            \"uglifyjs --verbose -b beautify=false --output=\""
            \.expand('%:p:r').".js\"",b:out
        \)
    el
        ec b:out
    en
    unl b:out
endf
```